# JS variable selection does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First I'd like to say that I saw an answer for this question on stackoverflow (mentioned down) but it didn't solve my problem.
for some reason the thisone variable at the bottom does not hide the element.
I also tried $("'#" + thisone + "'"), but it also didn't work.
However, alert shoes the correct id value (kida), and when I just replace thisone with $('#kida') it works. What is wrong?

```
$('input').click(function() {
  var thisone = this.id;
  var flname = this.alt.split(" ").splice(0, 2).join(" ");
  $("#pop").show(500);
  $("#fields").click(function() {
    if ($("#field").val() == "ani") {
      $('#pop').hide();
      alert(thisone);
      $(thisone).hide();
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: because the id is missing the "#" for the selector....

Comment: You're missing the hash to create the correct query for the id: $('#' + thisone). hide

Comment: Thanks, but I also tried $("'#" + thisone + "'").

Comment: Ok,  the extra ' ' were the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use

```
 $("#" + thisone )   // whitout single quote
```

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried $("'#" + thisone + "'"), but it also didn't work.

You don't need single quotes here before hash and after the id. Just write:

```
$("#" + thisone)
```